# Does 'google-drive' Web Component replaces the Google Drive Web APIs?

Tags: api, google-drive-api, polymer, web-component

The [google-apis](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-apis/components/google-apis/#google-client-api) together with [google-drive](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-drive/components/google-drive/) makes it super easy to add Google drive app integration to websites. But it seems that it doesn't have many options other than uploading files using app to the user google drive account.
I want to allow users to upload large files to my own google drive storage, will google web components achieve such task or I will need to dive into Google Drive Web APIs server side scripting, using PHP as an example.

Will Google Web Components support more features in the future like allowing users to upload to app google storage (my own google drive) ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a good place to ask that sort of question. Drop an issue into their github or like.

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Components not Polymer components. They are wrappers around Google API's like Drive. That said, I would pose this question in the context of the Drive API rather than in Polymer.

Comment: Yes, I was confused when I asked the question. Now its much clearer. Thanks